# C++ reading multiple input files sequentially

Tags: c++, c, input, vector

I have 47 different files:

- 001_template.dat
- ...
- 047_template.dat

in a directory called */data*. I need to compare each of these template files to three different query files, also in the directory. These are named:

- 001_AU01_query.dat
- 001_AU12_query.dat
- 001_AU17_query.dat.

I know how to get all of this to run, but I will have to cut and paste these 6 lines of code 46 more times and the program will get very long and confusing.

**Is there a good way to loop over these files?** Possibly by looping over the template files and then doing three queries for every template? I obviously have a similarity function and a sort function already defined, as well as `inputFile`. Here is the code I would like to convert: (not homework this is for a facial expression recognition project I have been working on)

```
int main()
{
vector<float> temp01;
vector<float> temp12;
vector<float> temp17;

temp01 = similar(inputFile("data/001_AU01_query.dat"), inputFile("data/001_template.dat"));
sortAndOutput(temp01);
temp12 = similar(inputFile("data/001_AU12_query.dat"), inputFile("data/001_template.dat"));
sortAndOutput(temp12);
temp17 = similar(inputFile("data/001_AU17_query.dat"), inputFile("data/001_template.dat"));
sortAndOutput(temp17);

}
```

Comment: Use a variable to hold the name of the file and loop of these files! You can construct a suitable string using `std::ostringstream` (you might need to use `str.c_str()` when opening a file).

Comment: copying and pasting that many times implies that you should use a function and/or a loop of some kind

Comment: Also take advantage of vectors since you seem to know how to use them.

Comment: So I could possibly use a vector of strings to hold the file names then. Hmmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then I would go with creating the file names with sprintf into the loop:

```
char data[100];
char template[100];
char* datas[3] = {"%3d_AU01_query.dat", "%3d_AU12_query.dat", "%3d_AU17_query.dat"};
for(i=0; i<47; i++){
  for{j=0; j<3; j++){
    sprintf(template, "%03d_template.dat", i);   // create the name of the template 1-47
    sprintf(data, datas[j], i);
    compare(template, data);
  }
}
```

That should work as expected I think.

Comment: perfect solution! thanks! I will post my final working code here also.

Comment: Would love to get points, but the good thing is that it works for you, good luck with your code :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use two arrays holding the names of files and templates and loop on them:

```
char* files[47] = {"file1", "file2", ...., "file47"};
char* templates[3] = {"template1", "template2", "template3"};
```

and loop on them:

```
for(i=0; i<47; i++){
  for{j=0; j<3; j++){
    compare(file[i],template[j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This works! Except for the fact that the template files also increment, so 002_template is the template searched when matching the queries for 002. So this comes really close, it compares all of the template files sequentially to the 001 queries. Thanks for the start at least!

Answer (score 0):

```
void work()
{


vector<float> temp;

char data[100];
char templates[100];
char* datas[3] = { "data/%03d_AU01_query.dat", "data/%03d_AU12_query.dat", "data/%03d_AU17_query.dat" };
for (int i = 1; i < 48; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        sprintf_s(templates, "data/%03d_template.dat", i);   // create the name of the template 1-47
        sprintf_s(data, datas[j], i);
        temp01 = similar(inputFile(data), inputFile(templates));
        sortAndOutput(temp);
    }
}
}
```